# unable to connect Kinesis data stream to Redshift via AWS glue job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I am trying push events inside my Kinesis data stream into Redshift cluster, and I am trying to achieve this via AWS Glue Job.

Using AWS Glue Studio, I am able to select my Kinesis Data stream as a `Source` but when I select on target and choose `AWS Redshift`, it does not load my Redshift Cluster that I have created.

What could be the problem?

I have verified that my Redshift is in the right region. :)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

First check that glue and redshift are in the same VPC.

Then check the security group. You will need to configure the security groups to allow traffic from Glue to Redshift. Add an inbound tcp rule that allows traffic to Redshift port. The source of the traffic should be the AWS Glue security group.

Finally check the IAM role you are using. Add the actions that you need to read from redshift.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "redshift:GetClusterCredentials",
            "redshift:DescribeClusters",
            "redshift:DescribeClusterSecurityGroups",
            "redshift:DescribeClusterParameterGroups",
            "redshift:DescribeClusterSubnetGroups",
            "redshift:DescribeClusterSnapshots",
            "redshift:DescribeClusterDbRevisions",
            "redshift:AuthorizeClusterSecurityGroupIngress",
            "redshift:AuthorizeClusterSecurityGroupEgress",
            "redshift:RevokeClusterSecurityGroupIngress",
            "redshift:RevokeClusterSecurityGroupEgress",
            "redshift:CreateClusterSnapshot",
            "redshift:RestoreFromClusterSnapshot"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:redshift:<region>:<account-id>:cluster:<cluster-id>"
    }
]}
```